# How to access the values of another feature in Specflow

Tags: specflow

I have two feature files feature1.feature and feature2.feature. In feature1.feature, I am creating a field value and adding it to FeatureContext.Current. Is there any possibility of accessing that value from feature2.feature?

I know that FeatureContext class will get cleared once the particular feature run is got over. Is there any other method for accessing values between two different feature files?

Please suggest some ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly advice against that setup. There's a couple of reasons for that:

- The technical reason: SpecFlow doesn't guarantee the order it runs either features of scenarios. You cannot trust it to always be the same.
- The business reason: The scenarios you're writing are first and foremost a communication tool. You want them to be easy to understand by themselves. When you talk about a particular scenario you shouldn't have to read through the other scenarios in the feature in order to understand what this special case does. It clogs up your communication around the scenario.

I suggest that you rather duplicated information in each scenario for readability. Should you end up with a lot of repeated information in each scenario you can you the [Background-feature of Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Background). These steps are run once before every scenario in the feature file and can be used to do repeated stuff.

Should you find yourself in a situation where you need to pass information back and forth between scenarios you should probably take a step back and reconsider your scenarios. Are these two different scenarios, really? Or is it maybe just one? How could you express them clearer?

I hope this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it, but maybe you can use the [BeforeFeature] and [AfterFeature] attributes to get the value from the featurecontext and set it in the the context of the next feature.